# How to serve other vhosts next to Gitlab Omnibus server? [Full step-by-step solution]

Tags: nginx, webserver, virtualhost, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I installed **Gitlab CE** on a dedicated Ubuntu 14.04 server edition with **Omnibus package**.

Now I would want to install three other **virtual hosts** next to gitlab.

Two are node.js web applications launched by a `non-root user` running on two distinct `ports > 1024`, the third is a PHP web application that need a web server to be launched from.

There are:

- a private bower registry running on `8081` (`node.js`)
- a private npm registry running on `8082` (`node.js`)
- a private composer registry (`PHP`)

But **Omnibus listen 80** and doesn't seem to use neither Apache2 or Nginx, **thus I can't use them to serve my PHP app and reverse-proxy my two other node apps**.

> What serving mechanics Gitlab Omnibus uses to `listen 80` ?
>   How should I create the three other virtual hosts to be able to provide the following vHosts ?
>
> - `gitlab.mycompany.com` (`:80`) -- already in use
> - `bower.mycompany.com` (`:80`)
> - `npm.mycompany.com` (`:80`)
> - `packagist.mycompany.com` (`:80`)

Comment: Did omnibus not use nginx as a web server ???

Comment: I guess not because nginx package isn't installed in the system ...

Comment: Oh yes indeed its the case ! I got it now. See the answer for the solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### About these

> But Omnibus listen 80 and doesn't seem to use neither Apache2 or Nginx [*, thus ...]*.

and @stdob comment :

> Did omnibus not use nginx as a web server ??? –

Wich I responded

> I guess not because nginx package isn't installed in the system ...

### In facts

From Gitlab official docs :

> By default, omnibus-gitlab installs GitLab with bundled Nginx.

So yes!

> **Omnibus package actually uses Nginx !**

but it was bundled, explaining why it doesn't require to be installed as dependency from the host OS.

Thus YES! **Nginx can, and should be used to serve my PHP app and reverse-proxy my two other node apps.**

## Then now

Omnibus-gitlab allows webserver access through user `gitlab-www` which resides
in the group with the same name. To allow an external webserver access to
GitLab, external webserver user needs to be added `gitlab-www` group.

To use another web server like Apache or an existing Nginx installation you will have to do
the following steps:

Disable bundled Nginx by specifying in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

```
nginx['enable'] = false
# For GitLab CI, use the following:
ci_nginx['enable'] = false
```

Check the username of the non-bundled web-server user. By default, `omnibus-gitlab` has no default setting for external webserver user.
You have to specify the external webserver user username in the configuration!
Let's say for example that webserver user is `www-data`.
In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` set

```
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
```

*This setting is an array so you can specify more than one user to be added to gitlab-www group.*

Run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the change to take effect.

### Setting the NGINX listen address or addresses

By default NGINX will accept incoming connections on all local IPv4 addresses.
You can change the list of addresses in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.

```
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ["0.0.0.0", "[::]"] # listen on all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses
```

For GitLab CI, use the `ci_nginx['listen_addresses']` setting.

### Setting the NGINX listen port

By default NGINX will listen on the port specified in `external_url` or
implicitly use the right port (80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS). If you are running
GitLab behind a reverse proxy, you may want to override the listen port to
something else.  For example, to use port 8080:

```
nginx['listen_port'] = 8080
```

Similarly, for GitLab CI:

```
ci_nginx['listen_port'] = 8081
```

### Supporting proxied SSL

By default NGINX will auto-detect whether to use SSL if `external_url`
contains `https://`.  If you are running GitLab behind a reverse proxy, you
may wish to keep the `external_url` as an HTTPS address but communicate with
the GitLab NGINX internally over HTTP. To do this, you can disable HTTPS using
the `listen_https` option:

```
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

Similarly, for GitLab CI:

```
ci_nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

Note that you may need to configure your reverse proxy to forward certain
headers (e.g. `Host`, `X-Forwarded-Ssl`, `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Port`) to GitLab.

You may see improper redirections or errors (e.g. "422 Unprocessable Entity",
"Can't verify CSRF token authenticity") if you forget this step. For more
information, see:

- [What's the de facto standard for a Reverse Proxy to tell the backend SSL is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042647/whats-the-de-facto-standard-for-a-reverse-proxy-to-tell-the-backend-ssl-is-used)
- https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy

> To go further you can follow the official docs at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server

## Configuring our gitlab virtual host

### Installing Phusion Passenger

We need to install ruby (gitlab run in omnibus with a bundled ruby) globally in the OS

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install ruby
$ sudo gem install passenger
```

### Recompile nginx with the passenger module

Instead of `Apache2` for example, nginx isn't able to be plugged with binary modules on-the-fly. It must be recompiled for each new plugin you want to add.

Phusion passenger developer team worked hard to provide saying, "[a bundled nginx version of passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html)" : nginx bins compiled with passenger plugin.

So, lets use it:

> **requirement**: we need to open our `TCP` port `11371` (the `APT key` port).

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

creating `passenger.list`

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

with these lignes

```
# Ubuntu 14.04
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main
```

> use the right repo for your ubuntu version. For Ubuntu 15.04 for example: 
>      deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger vivid main

Edit permissions:

```
$ sudo chown root: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
$ sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

Updating package list:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Allowing it as `unattended-upgrades`

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

Find or create this config block on top of the file:

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {

  // you may have some instructions here

};
```

Add the following:

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {

  // you may have some instructions here

  // To check "Origin:" and "Suite:", you could use e.g.:
  // grep "Origin\|Suite" /var/lib/apt/lists/oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com*
    "Phusion:stable";

};
```

#### Now (re)install `nginx-extra` and `passenger`:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.bak_"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)"
$ sudo apt-get install nginx-extras passenger
```

#### configure it

Uncomment the `passenger_root` and `passenger_ruby` directives in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

... to obtain something like:

```
##
# Phusion Passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
##

passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
```

#### create the nginx site configuration (the virtual host conf)

```
$ nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab.conf

server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name gitlab.mycompany.com;
  server_tokens off;
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  client_max_body_size 250m;
  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  # Ensure Passenger uses the bundled Ruby version
  passenger_ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby;

  # Correct the $PATH variable to included packaged executables
  passenger_env_var PATH "/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";

  # Make sure Passenger runs as the correct user and group to
  # prevent permission issues
  passenger_user git;
  passenger_group git;

  # Enable Passenger & keep at least one instance running at all times
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_min_instances 1;

  error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```

Now we can enable it:

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab.cong /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

> There is no `a2ensite` equivalent coming natively with nginx, so we use `ln`, but if you want, there is a project on github:
>   [**nginx_ensite**](https://github.com/perusio/nginx_ensite):
>   **nginx_ensite and nginx_dissite for quick virtual host enabling and disabling**
>
> This is a shell (Bash) script that replicates for nginx the Debian a2ensite and a2dissite for enabling and disabling sites as virtual hosts in Apache 2.2/2.4.

#### It' done :-). Finally, restart nginx

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

## With this new configuration, you are able to run other virtual hosts next to gitlab to serve what you want

Just create new configs in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`.

> In my case, I made running and serving this way on the same host :

- gitlab.mycompany.com - the [awesome git platform](https://about.gitlab.com/) written in ruby
- ci.mycompany.com - the [gitlab continuous integration server](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/) written in ruby
- npm.mycompany.com - a private [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) registry written in `node.js`
- bower.mycompany.com - a private [bower](http://bower.io/search/) registry written in `node.js`
- packagist.mycompany.com -  a private [packagist](https://packagist.org/explore/) for [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) registry written in php

For example, to serve `npm.mycompany.com` :

Create a directory for logs:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/log/private-npm/nginx/
```

And fill a new vhost config file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/npm.conf
```

With this config

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name npm.mycompany.com

  client_max_body_size 5m;
  access_log  /var/log/private-npm/nginx/npm_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/private-npm/nginx/npm_error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Then enable it and restart it:

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/npm.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: I cannot restart gitlab bundle nginx using this commang `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: You shoud create a new question post on stackoverflow and explain your issue in details. Have you got an error message ? etc ... Then share the permalink here I will help you with pleasure.

Comment: I have created a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969612/how-can-i-restart-bundle-nginx-in-gitlab-separately) .

Comment: Thank you too, @TheF! So... you could upvote the question too, it will help to earn more visibility ;-)

Comment: @RémiBecheras A very good tutorial. Saved my life :P. Indeed very good step by step instructions. Thanks a lot. I just want to add. People trying to install passenger with ruby version less than 2.2.2, they need to trick the bundler by `em install rack -v=1.6.4` and then `gem install passenger -v=5.0.10 --conservative`.

Comment: @RémiBecheras btw I am experiencing one problem. When i git clone, it clones empty repository. Any idea?

Comment: See dgoo2308's answer for a much better answer. This solution explains in a lot of unnecessary words (what's got passenger to do with creating other nginx vhosts) how to disable the bundled nginx and install your own - which you would then have to manage, update and configure yourself.

Comment: Heads up, one thing that wasn't mentioned -- if your nginx won't start (and passes `nginx -t` test), the error logs will show the old gitlab nginx is still running on port 80! If you reinstall an existing Nginx installation, use the reconfigure command [again] to disable gitlab's nginx

Comment: @RémiBecheras **Recompile nginx with the passenger module** should run on nginx server or gitlab server in my case nginx server is sitting on different vhost.

Comment: This solution is much harder and "hackier" than the alternative proposed by @Danny - just insert the custom vHost definitions into the bundled nginx

Comment: FYI this solution is to use an alternate server to resolve hosting vhosts next to  gitlab https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server, where i think the op was asking how to add vhosts to gitlab, using what it has, to host other sites https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#inserting-custom-settings-into-the-nginx-config (see @danny answer below for elaboration on the latter).

Answer (score 27):

As I would not like to change the nginx server for gitlab (with some other integrations), the safest way would be below solution.

also as per

[Gitlab:Ningx =>Inserting custom settings into the NGINX config](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#inserting-custom-settings-into-the-nginx-config)

edit the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb of your gitlab:

```
nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

and sroll to nginx['custom_nginx_config'] and modify as below make sure to uncomment

```
# Example: include a directory to scan for additional config files
nginx['custom_nginx_config'] = "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;"
```

create the new config dir:

```
mkdir -p /etc/nginx/conf.d/
nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/new_app.conf
```

and add content to your new config

```
# my new app config : /etc/nginx/conf.d/new_app.conf
# set location of new app 
upstream new_app {
  server localhost:1234; # wherever it might be
}
# set the new app server
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name new_app.mycompany.com;
  server_tokens off;
  access_log  /var/log/new_app_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/new_app_error.log;
  proxy_set_header Host      $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  location / { proxy_pass  http://new_app; }
}
```

and reconfigure gitlab to get the new settings inserted

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

to restart nginx

```
gitlab-ctl restart nginx
```

to check nginx error log:

```
tail -f /var/log/gitlab/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: Nice instructions. I would add however two things that need fixing. The server and proxy_pass lines need a trailing ';' and the proxy_pass line must be in a location context. Like : 

    upstream app {
        server localhost:8080;
    }

    server {
       listen *:80;
       server_name app.domain.com;
       server_tokens off;
       access_log  /var/log/app_access.log;
       error_log /var/log/app_error.log;
       proxy_set_header Host      $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       location / {
         proxy_pass  http://app;
       }
    }

Comment: Please note - the proxy_pass directive belongs to a location directive

Comment: You could better use the latest `master` branch: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md

Comment: @Danny Great answer. Is there a way to add Let's Encrypt for such domain on the Gitlab Nginx? In this example, for 'new_app.mycompany.com'?

Comment: @Slavik run `sudo certbot --nginx` and do it that way. Thanks to @Danny too because this saved me a real headache

Comment: @MattFletcher running `sudo certbot --nginx` returns `The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed`. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: oh i just realized... plugin just needs to be installed, since gitlab is using manual method. I was concerned not to break anything by installing it (or that it was already installed, just not initializing), but everything works ok!