# How can I restart bundle nginx in gitlab separately?

Tags: nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have installed Gitlab CE version. I can find nginx bundled in Gitlab. However I cannot find a way to restart nginx separately. I have tried `sudo service nginx restart` but it gives:

```
* Restarting nginx nginx                                     [fail]
```

I have checked all the document but cannot find a solution. I am trying to add vhost to the bundled nginx according to this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31781049/1820217). But I stuck at that step. Is there other way to add vhost to bundled nginx with Gitlab? Or How can I check whether my nginx conf work?

Edit: 502 error I have solved.

I try to use NON-bundle nginx according to this [doc](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server) , But after I modify `gitlab.rb` and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` , I got `502 Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond.` error.

Here is my `gitlab.conf` for nginx.

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix://var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-git-http-server/sockets/gitlab.socket fail_timeout=0;
  #
}

server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name blcu.tk;
  server_tokens off;
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  client_max_body_size 250m;

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;


# Ensure Passenger uses the bundled Ruby version
passenger_ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby;

# Correct the $PATH variable to included packaged executables
passenger_env_var PATH "/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";

# Make sure Passenger runs as the correct user and group to
# prevent permission issues
passenger_user git;
passenger_group git;

# Enable Passenger & keep at least one instance running at all times
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_min_instances 1;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
}

 location @gitlab {
    # If you use https make sure you disable gzip compression 
    # to be safe against BREACH attack

    proxy_read_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
  location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    # gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }


  error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```

Comment: To serve other vhosts, you checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762841/how-to-serve-other-vhosts-next-to-gitlab-omnibus-server-full-step-by-step-solu

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To restart only one component of GitLab Omnibus you can execute `sudo gitlab-ctl restart <component>`. Therefore, to restart Nginx:

`sudo gitlab-ctl restart nginx`

As a further note, this same concept is possible with nearly all of the `gitlab-ctl` commands. For example, `sudo gitlab-ctl tail` allows you to see all GitLab logs. Applying this concept, `sudo gitlab-ctl tail nginx` will tail only Nginx logs.

Answer (score 0):

My tuto explains how to add vhosts to a NON-bundled nginx server, not the bundled one.

The steps are :

- disable the bundled version
- install a standalone nginx version compiled with passenger module,
- configure it to serve gitlab as a vhost
- and then configure other custom vhosts on it.

If `sudo service nginx restart` return

```
* Restarting nginx nginx                                     [fail]
```

then you probably installed nginx separately with something like `sudo apt-get install nginx` or you installed the recompiled version with pushion passenger module as I explain in my tuto ?

Do you really use the bundled version or you misunderstood this step in my tuto ?

> Please answer these questions in comments then I will edit this answer to write the solution you really need.

Comment: I must miss some steps, I forget I must use NON-bundled version nginx.

Comment: After I use non bundle version nginx I met 502 error.

Comment: Really thank you for your help. I forget the step to use the NON-bundle nginx. I remember I have install the nginx, but forget to modify the `gitlab.rb` file and reconfigure.

Answer (score -2):

To restart bundled nginx do `sudo gitlab-ctl restart`

Comment: It wants to restart a single service *separately* from the rest.