# Can't stop Gitlab's built-in Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm using Gitlabs latest Omnibus-package on an EC2 Ubuntu machine.

To refresh my SSL certificate (issued via Let's Encrypt) I need to stop Gitlab's Nginx so Let's Encrypt can verify that I possess the domain.
Therefore I hit `sudo gitlab-ctl stop`.

The `sudo gitlab-ctl status` afterwards is:

```
down: gitlab-workhorse: 325s, normally up; run: log: (pid 1109) 5361843s
down: logrotate: 324s, normally up; run: log: (pid 1104) 5361843s
down: nginx: 324s, normally up; run: log: (pid 1103) 5361843s
down: postgresql: 324s, normally up; run: log: (pid 1101) 5361843s
down: redis: 323s, normally up; run: log: (pid 1102) 5361843s
down: sidekiq: 322s, normally up; run: log: (pid 1112) 5361842s
down: unicorn: 322s, normally up; run: log: (pid 1100) 5361843s
```

However when I access my domain I get Nginx' `502 Bad Gateway`.

How can I truly stop its internal Nginx.

Besides the certificate part the `etc/nginx/gitlab.rb` is still the default.

Here's the output of `ps -eaf|grep -i nginx`

```
root      1091   985  0  2015 ?        00:07:15 runsv nginx
root      1103  1091  0  2015 ?        00:04:14 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/nginx
gitlab-+ 24669     1  0  2015 ?        01:03:38 nginx: worker process
root     27272  1091  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
ubuntu   27275 27254  0 13:12 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i nginx
```

Comment: Is it related to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/issues/136#note_1196543? (the error itself can also mean https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1527#issuecomment-8821679)

Comment: From what I read the other people are actually trying to run Gitlab. All I want is to stop its Nginx.

Comment: If you have access to the server, do you see an nginx process still running?

Comment: I don't know where to look for it. It is neither installed as a service (`sudo service --status-all`) neither `initctl` (`sudo initctl list`)

Comment: I mean: `ps -eaf|grep -i nginx` return nothing?

Comment: I added the output to the question.

Comment: Don't you have a reverse proxy ahead of your gitlab instance ? Seems it's something else than gitlab that answer 502

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, I have. But it is stopped independently of gitlab (`nginx stop`)

Comment: You seems to still have something in between which answer to external request, contact your netadmin ...

Comment: Just run this sudo gitlab-ctl stop nginx https://stackoverflow.com/a/32974637

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness sake what I ended up doing three years ago was what @user8215365 suggested.
Simply invoking `sudo gitlab-ctl stop nginx` did the trick.