# 502 Gitlab is taking too much time to respond

Tags: nginx, gitlab, connection-timeout, gitlab-omnibus

After taking gitlab backup everyday gitlab is throwing 502 error.
I saw nginx logs but did not find that much information.

[image]

After   `gitlab-ctl restart` it starts working again.

System Configurations:
OS : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
4 GB Ram
200 GB Disk Space

can anyone give permanent solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search i got something about it. After taking backup my `gitlab-workhorse` is getting ideal and `gitlab.socket` is refusing the connection. As temporary solution i have installed a new cron job for restarting gitlab service after the complpetion of  gitlab backup cronjob.

Answer (score 3):

There is a high possibility that it run out of shared memory. As each time after the backup you got the 502 error.

To check it with `gitlab-ctl tail` [tail detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32974637/6521116)

It will show something like:

```
2019-04-12_12:37:17.27154 FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
2019-04-12_12:37:17.27157 HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 4345470976 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
2019-04-12_12:37:17.27171 LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Then check it with `free -m`, which shows there is no available shared memory.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         16081      13715       2365          0        104        753
-/+ buffers/cache:      12857       3223
```

Then you need to check if there is some process take too many shared memory, or too many zomibe process, then kill it with command like `ps -aef | grep ffmpeg | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill 9`

Check it with `free -h`, there is about `112M` shared memory now.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G       4.4G        11G       112M        46M       416M
-/+ buffers/cache:       3.9G        11G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

At last,restart you gitlab with `gitlab-ctl restart`, after sometime the gitlab booted, the 502 gone.

Answer (score 0):

If the gitlab is installed in `Virtual-Box` -  `Ubuntu server` either `18.04` or `20.04`,

> please increase the RAM to **`4gb`** and the provide atleast **`3 processors`**.