# Unable to locate and reload Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 (Nginx was installed by gitLab)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm unable to reload my Nginx.

If I do `sudo /bin/systemctl reload nginx`, I get: `Failed to reload nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not found.`

If I do `nginx -t` or `nginx -V`, I get:

`The program 'nginx' can be found in the following packages:
 * nginx-core
 * nginx-extras
 * nginx-full
 * nginx-light`

If I do `which nginx`, I get absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't manage nginx service nor run it's commands, it's not actually installed (not in the usual way). That means either you ran nginx manually using a binary you downloaded or you're running these commands in an isolated environment (less likely).

Just download it again using apt to avoid further headaches.

Comment: oh yes maybe!  I think the Nginx came with the gitLab package I installed.  Any way I can locate it?

Comment: maybe reinstalling it will create some conflicts?

Comment: I've been through the same when installing Nexus lol. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776148/how-to-find-a-file-in-ubuntu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) might help

Comment: If it actually came along when you downloaded something else, it's better to check gitlab's docs for hints on how to handle this. It's very likely you can install it with no big issues (gitlab likes using new versions of things), but better safe than sorry

Comment: thanks for you help! you gave me an idea, and I was able to find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969612/how-can-i-restart-bundle-nginx-in-gitlab-separately

Comment: Makes sense, glad I could help :)