# Specify nginx PID for certbot (for gitlab bundled nginx)

Tags: nginx, gitlab, certbot

I'm running a server with GitLab on it, and want to be able to use nginx for other services too (in my instance, Jenkins). I've modified the GL config to add additional vhosts [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39695791/1025702) and it's all working fine.

However, I want to also set an SSL certificate with certbot, however when I run `sudo certbot --nginx`, I get the following:

```
nginx: [error] invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"
```

I presume this is because GitLab's nginx instance isn't putting a pid into the run dir like a normal nginx instance would. So, my question is either:

**Can GitLab be configured to create a PID here?**

... or

**Can certbot be configured to look for a PID elsewhere?**

Comment: (Ps, I know I can just do it manually and then edit the nginx myself, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it automatically as it's a bit of a PITA)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a pretty simple workaround for this...

```
cat /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/nginx.pid > /run/nginx.pid
```

You put this in a script or execute it before executin `certbot --nginx` command

It's not the best solution, but it seems that certbot doesn't have an option to specify pid path.

EDIT: Explanation

Gitlab omnibus nginx pid file is located in `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/nginx.pid`, this way we just write the same PID to the location that certbot is looking by default (or perhaps misinterpreted config)